# Properties of $R/I$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $a$ be an irreducible element of $R$.  Let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $a$.

1.If $R$ is a principal ideal domain, $R/I$ is a field ?

True. Since $a$ is irreducible, $I$ is maximal among proper principal ideals of $R.$ Since $R$ is PID, every ideal of $R$ is the form of $(r),$ $r \in R.$ Hence, $I$ is maximal and $R/I$ is a field.

2.If $R$ is a unique factorization domain, then $R/I$ is a field ?

False ?

Could someone advise me on the correct approach to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your favorite non-PID UFD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As before, recall that $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ maximal. Consider $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, the element $2$; and the ideals $(2)$, $(2,X)$.

Answer (score 0):

2) is false in general.  For example, consider polynomials in 2 variables over a field $\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ which is a UFD but not a PID.  Then $y$ is irreducible but $\mathbb{k}[x,y]/(y) = \mathbb{k}[x]$

Comment: Thank you! May I know how one prove that $\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ is not PID? (Sorry if the question sounds trivial)

Comment: Polynomials over a ring are a PID iff the ring is a field.  So here we view $\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ as polynomials in $y$ over the ring $\mathbb{k}[x]$ which is not a field.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is field, but $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[X]$ is not field( for eg, $X \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[X]$ has no multiplicative inverse)?

Comment: Polynomials over an integral domain can't be a field by additivity of degree.